# I want my google assistant application to talk to my webserver first and then dialogflow

Tags: php, node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want my Google Assistant application to talk to my webserver first and then Dialogflow. The way DialogFlow is documented, the Assistant talks to it first, and then it is passed to my webhook. I want to do it the other way.

[image: Technical architecture of google assistant]

Comment: How in the world is this "too broad"? It is a fairly specific question asking for architecture required to do something. Perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

To have the Google Assistant talk directly to your server (without Dialogflow in between) you need to use the [Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/). You'll create an [actions.json](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/create-a-project) file which defines triggering information and the URL for a webhook. (You can't get rid of the webhook - just change how it is called.) Your webhook will be called with JSON that has a different format from Dialogflow's JSON format, or you can use the node.js library which has a similar interface to the Dialogflow version.

Your webhook can, then, call Dialogflow using the [/query endpoint](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query) (for Dialogflow V1 API) or the [detectIntent message](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) (for the Dialogflow V2 API). You can send it the text from the user or an event indicating the user's action (or, really, anything you want) along with parameters and Contexts that you wish. Dialogflow will send a reply, either from it's reply section or by sending it to *another* fulfilment webhook - whatever you choose.

Your server will get this reply, along with any Contexts and parameters that are set. It sounds like you'll send the reply to the user, probably without further processing, although you can do whatever you want. You may want to store the context information in the [conversation token](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse), the [user storage object](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse), or in some other data store your server wishes to use.

There are some [samples for using the Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/#actions-sdk) although none of them illustrate calling Dialogflow from the webhook. (It is not a very common pattern - most use cases work better the other way.) The [samples for Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/docs/examples/) are mostly for webhooks, although the "Agent to human handoff" does illustrate sending to Dialogflow from your code.

Comment: yes sir i did that. but can u suggest me some better actions sdk projects to get the hands on actions sdk.

Comment: Updated answer to provide some links.